# (jquery) Blackout the entire screen and highlight a section of the page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

As per screenshot below. I am pretty sure someone has done this before! =)

The circle is a bonus, would be very happy with a solution that allows highlighting of a given "div"

[image: only part of the screen highlighted]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[**See example of the following here →**](http://jsfiddle.net/QVCTW/1/)

No need for a plugin.  This can be accomplished with very little jQuery code, showing a blackout overlay with the selected div at a z-index above it:

```
$('.expose').click(function(e){
    $(this).css('z-index','99999');
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);
});

$('#overlay').click(function(e){
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(300, function(){
        $('.expose').css('z-index','1');
    });
});
```

According to the following HTML & CSS...  just add the `expose` class to any element you want isolated on click:

```
<div class="expose">Some content</div>
<textarea class="expose">Some content</textarea><br />
<input type="text" class="expose" value="Some content" /><br />
<div id="overlay"></div>

.expose {
    position:relative;
}

#overlay {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display:none;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:99998;
}
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/QVCTW/1/)

Comment: Short and sweet! By changing `#overlay`'s background to `#000` and using `fadeTo(300, 0.3)` will make it work in IE as well (at least the IE8 that I am testing with).

Comment: Thx I used "position: fixed" to stop people being able to scroll away from it

Comment: It's not always so easy.  If you are having trouble with this, read about "stacking contexts"  http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: keep in mind that this does not work for child elements.

Comment: @Paul's link is great - I got bit by the target element was contained in an opacity < 1, so it didn't stack on top of the overlay. Added to the script to set that element's opacity to 1, and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

What about using the **outline CSS property**?

```
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background:url('icons.png') #fff no-repeat 5px -601px;
    padding:0 10px 0 32px!important;
    width:168px;
    outline: 0px rgba(0,0,0,0) solid;
    transition: outline-color .3s
}
input[type="search"]:focus{
    z-index:1000;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #f60;
    outline: 5000px rgba(0,0,0,.8) solid ;
}
```

this applies a very large outline on focused inputs with fade transition.

Example:

> [image]

Comment: I was happy to see this answer and tested it (http://jsfiddle.net/mkormendy/mhc4obm9/) with two small caveats: 1. The size of the outline needs to be larger than your page scroll; 2. changing the transition to "outline .3s" fades out the transition on clicking outside the element.

Answer (score 6):

Look at [jQuery Tool's Expose plugin](http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/toolbox/expose.html). That's probably what you want.

Comment: The URL is dead at this date : 2013-02-28

Comment: @Purefan Looks like they forgo the domain and has moved the project to Github http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/toolbox/expose.html

Answer (score 4):

**5 years since the question was asked**, but it may help people arriving from google

I've developed a plugin for this matter,

You can get it from: [Hop on Github](https://github.com/ahmad-moussawi/hop)

[image: Hop Logo]

Let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I played off @mVChr's fiddle to highlight one box once a different button is clicked. I'm currently using this to highlight an entry field once a login button is clicked on a new site.

```
$('.expose').click(function(e){
    $('.lightbox').css('z-index','99999');
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);
});

$('#overlay').click(function(e){
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(300, function(){
        $('.expose').css('z-index','1');
    });
});
```

[Modified example based on @mVChr's code](http://jsfiddle.net/casemorton/S4FtY/)

```
<div class="buttonbox expose">When clicked</div>
<div class="lightbox expose">This box lights up</div><br /><br />
<div id="overlay"></div>

.buttonbox {     
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    color:#1792C7;
    border: 1px solid #1792C7; 
    padding:10px 16px;
    background-color:transparent;
    -webkit-transition: background linear .3s; 
    -moz-transition: background linear .3s; 
    -ms-transition: background linear .3s; 
    -o-transition: background linear .3s; 
    transition: background linear .3s; 
}

.buttonbox:hover { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #fff; 
    background-color: #1792C7; 
}

.lightbox {     
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #0d0d0d;
    color: #0d0d0d;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 5px; 
    padding:10px 16px;
    text-align:center;
}

.expose {
    position:relative;
}

#overlay {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display:none;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:99998;
}
```