# Circular highlight css3

Tags: html, css

how to make a circular highlight over any object on a site....

I been looking around and can't find almost any documentation for this. Although I seem to believe that anything is possible now with css, something tells me this would only be available with something like canvas and take a lot of memory.

The only other post I've seen about this is this one...
[(jquery) Blackout the entire screen and highlight a section of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399442/jquery-blackout-the-entire-screen-and-highlight-a-section-of-the-page)
although they didnt address the circular issue there

I've seen on a few sites how to highlight a certain element, but how exactly would you make the highlighted area a circle? By only adding z-index to make a square element show above the overlay, it seems impossible to make the area a circle..

Maybe I could z-index every element that would be included in the circle and create a shadow around the edges the same color as the overlay(but if the spotlight needs to run onto part of the background i would need to include the entire background and that could turn ugly)...this may work actually, in certain cases, but that sounds a bit jenky, no?

anyone have a good solution for highlighting objects on a page but that highlight being a circle / almost like spotlighting a element...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `border-radius` and `box-shadow` at least that's the only way I can think of with **pure** css

What you do is you make an element that is circle with a `transparent` background, then you give it a `box-shadow` completely black that will fill the whole of your page, and you can get some amazing effects.

Example code

```css
#torch{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px #000, 0px 0px 50px inset;
}
```

Don't forget to add your prefixes `-moz-, -webkit- ..etc` and don't forget your `z-index` if you need it.

## [Demo at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLNAF/)

Comment: ya this is extrememly clever...how come i didnt think of that, lol...im going to try to apply this really quick then give you the answer

Comment: wooow I just realized how incredibly simple that was.

Heres a fiddle I made from it, is there a way to be able to interact with the elements below? Thanks so much! http://jsfiddle.net/MLNAF/2/

Answer (score 2):

By using `border-radius` to make the circle and for the other stuff may be this can help you..http://jquerytools.org/demos/toolbox/expose/

Answer (score 1):

Just use `border-radius` to make the container you want to "expose" a circle.

Using the jsfiddle example from your linked post, i've trimmed it down to be easier to follow, but essentially, you just need to use the post you linked to along with a big border radius value to mimic a circle.

http://jsfiddle.net/98EAt/

Comment: what about if there is content inside? Here is an example I put together really quickly from your jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98EAt/1/

I dont need to highlight a circular element, but highlight a square element with a circular highlight. Thanks for the work with the fiddle too!!

Answer (score -1):

**2 years since the question was asked,**

I've developed a plugin for this matter,

[image: Hop Logo]

Let me know your feedback.