# How to highlight specific control with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've seen this functionality when I'm signing up for account on some website or when there is some update and the website wants to put the focus on that control. The rest of the page has some shadow layer and only some specific part of the website is highlighted along with some explanation/description about that control.

How we can do that?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show your code.

Comment: nothing, I don't know how to start and I don't know how to look for examples for the thing I want to achieve. Thanks for your reply. @rje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean the focus attribute:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Comment: not focus on the actual control, but like a overlay except that overlay will not cover one specific control until user action. Thanks

Comment: In that case, I think your question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399442/jquery-blackout-the-entire-screen-and-highlight-a-section-of-the-page

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the autofocus attribute defined in html5. Combine this with our CSS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a validation plugin? There are tons of them out there, for example the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are expecting answer like this as simple with z-index;

[`See the Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/b71hxfur/)

[Also this](http://jsfiddle.net/QVCTW/1/)
Answerd by [mVChr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246616/mvchr)