# Blackout entire page and highlight div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried this approach without any luck: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399442/jquery-blackout-the-entire-screen-and-highlight-a-section-of-the-page). The problem is that the blackout is not triggered - nothing happens.

My JavaScript code looks like this (all of the code is embedded within the `$(document).ready(function ()` tag)

```js
// Show MicroClean Details window
$(function () {
    $("#MicroCleanClick").click(function () {
        $("#GraphBox").show();
        $(this).css("z-index","99999");
        $("#overlay").fadeIn(300);
        loadGraph();
        return false;
    });
});

// Remove blackout
$("#overlay").click(function (e) {
    $("#overlay").fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(".expose").css("z-index", "1");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="MicroCleanClick" href="#" class="button">Show Data</a>
               
<div class="expose" id="GraphBox">

    <p class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="temperature" value="temp"> Temperature <input type="checkbox" name="relHumidity" value="relhum"> Rel. Humidity</p>
    <p class="datepicker">From: <input type="text" id="fromDate"> To: <input type="text" id="toDate" ></p>

    <canvas id="myChart" width=800 height="450"></canvas>
    <div id="legendDiv"></div><br>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Here is the CSS code for `#overlay` and `.expose`:

```
.expose {
    position:relative;

}

#overlay {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display:none;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    z-index:99998;
}
```

Comment: where is your element w/ id `overlay`?

Comment: Why is your click event being wrapped in an anonymous function anyway? You said all your JS is inside a document ready function, right?

Comment: How about using intro.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `$(this).css("z-index","99999");` should be corrected, so the actual element what needs to stay on top of the blackout is present: `$("#GraphBox").css("z-index", "99999");`.

In this case the element staying on top is the `<div id="GraphBox">...</div>`.

Also, all the anonymous function wrappers should be removed for clarity and correctness:

```
// Show MicroClean Details window
$("#MicroCleanClick").click(function () {
    $("#GraphBox").show();
    $("#GraphBox").css("z-index", "99999");
    $("#overlay").fadeIn(300);
    loadGraph();
    return false;
});


// Close MicroClean Details Window
$("#overlay").click(function (e) {
    $("#overlay").fadeOut(300, function () {
        $("#GraphBox").hide();
    });
});
```

Remember to add `display:none;` to the `#GraphBox` in the CSS file. Otherwise `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` want trigger.

To ensure the element in top of the blackout closes in the same time as the blackout, add `$("#GraphBox").hide();` in:

```
$("#overlay").click(function (e) {
    $("#overlay").fadeOut(300, function () {
        $("#GraphBox").hide();
    });
});
```

The code is tested in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

The first issue I see is that you don't have a `<div id='overlay'>` which needs to be styled like this:

```
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Once you add that and style it, everything should be working just fine. [See this jsfiddle for an example](https://jsfiddle.net/hxq4nd6g/), although its not entirely clear from the question which data you want to be showing when the black div is visible.

Also, note that `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` animate the display property, so you'll have to start any element which will be targeted by `fadeIn()` with `display: none;`

https://jsfiddle.net/hxq4nd6g/

Comment: This is correct, I would only add that `$(this).css("z-index","99999");` should be replaced with CSS class `$(this).addClass('stand-out');` and `.stand-out` class should have `position:relative` and `z-index: 99999`. That helps separating the responsibility between JS and CSS, and also helps maintaining the code, since it will be possible to improve/adjust styling later on without changing the javascript code.

Comment: Thanks @AntonBoritskiy - that is definitely an improvement.

Comment: @knolljm I have updated my question with the missing CSS code - I'm sorry! The data I want to show is all the code in the ´id="GraphBox"´ tag.